# How to add a radio button in bootstrap dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

anyone can you please help me how to add a radio button inside of dropdown option. here i am trying to add button getting radio button outside of the dropdown [image]

Please have a look on this ref... images.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
  <style>
  .pos{position:absolute;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input pos" value="">
    <span>ption 2</span>
      
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input pos" value="">
    <span>ption 2</span>
      
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input pos" value="">
    <span>ption 2</span>
      
      </div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this html stucture for radio button

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option1" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
    option 2
  </label>
</div>
```

**Working Demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
  <style>
  .pos{position:absolute;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
    option 1
  </label>
</div>  
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
     <div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option1" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
    option 2
  </label>
</div> 
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option1" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
    option 3
  </label>
</div> 
      
      </div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited the answer and added radio button structure. Use that structure to fix your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You Shold try this code!

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input pos" value="">
          <label class="form-check-label">ption 2</label>      
      </div>      
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input pos" value="">
         <label class="form-check-label">ption 2</label>
      
      </div>      
      <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input pos" value="">
             <label class="form-check-label">ption 2</label>      
      </div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. See [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Comment: Sir thank you, but option value should be displayed in dropdown button please have let me know how to do that.

Comment: Sorry , but I m not getting your point what you want.